# Integer programming using the Steinitz lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, integer-programming

I am trying to implement an algorithm that I read on the paper entitled: *"Proximity results and faster algorithms for integer programming using the Steinitz lemma"*, published by Friedrich Eisenbrand and Robert Weismantel https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.00481.

In the first algorithm: section 2 "A faster dynamic program", the paper explains how to use the Steinitz lemma to create a digraph. The digraph is composed by a set $S$ of vertices and a set $A$ of edges. The set $S$ is defined using a parameter t, which is defined to be the norm of the vector z*. The vector z* is the solution vector.

Question: How can I define the norm of the solution vector if I don't know what is the solution?